# ubuntu zfs mount needs to be delayed?

Tags: ubuntu, zfs, automount

I have a ZFS pool that came out of a freenas box.  I exported it from there and imported it into a Ubuntu 11.10 box.  This has ZFS native installed (Darik Horn's ZFS PPA) which is working fine (i think). The Ubuntu system in installed on a mirrored pair of 320gb laptop drives.

When booting, I sometimes get a 'waiting for hdd warning' on boot (the volume is a copy of another active zfs volume so I dont mind if it gets trashed while I am playing).

Once I am logged in, a zpool status shows that I have corrupted data on random volumes and the recommendation to trash and rebuild.  It once did a resilver when only one drive was showing errors.

If I export the volume and then import -f it, it is fine.  No data corruptions and the volume is mounted ok.

Using gsmartcontrol shows that all drives in the volume have PASSED.

Are my zpool problems a sign of a hdd about to die?  Or just the timing of when things are ready to be mounted.  Can I delay mounting the zfs until the drives are ready?

Any suggestions are most welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Ignore the SMART status. Few drives report SMART accurately.

If the BIOS is reporting delayed spin-up, and ZFS is reporting checksum errors, then the disk is indeed bad.